# Save a C# object to disk without serializing it?

Tags: c#, asp.net, serialization

We have an existing asp.net 4.0 website that uses the HttpRuntime.Cache for a lot of things. It was created like this before I started working on it and now we're having problems with the cache being cleared and the website falling over because it always expects the cache to be there (I know... what did they think a cache was!?).

So what I need is a replacement cache that is permanent so I can swap it for the HttpRuntime.Cache with no impact to the website. I've looked at serialization but not all the objects are serializable and it's not an option to make them all serializable (there are way too many of them scattered all over).

Is there a way to save any in memory object/variable/whatever to disk, and read it later, without having to serialize it?

**Update:**

Thanks for your comments and answer so far. Starting with your ideas I did some more Googling and came across this article that demonstrates (with an example solution you can download) how to use your own custom caching provider in .Net 4.0. I haven't been able to integrate it into our web application and give it a proper test yet (hopefully later today I'll be able to) but I thought I'd put it here to see if you have any thoughts about it... so what do you think, any caveats I should be aware of? Or is this a viable (and *very* temporary) solution?

[File-Based Cache for Web and non-Web Apps plus Extend ASP.NET 4.0 OutputCacheProvider](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/tutorials/asp-net/56161e9e-7fa3-48e8-9dfe-9f7a28f4d58e/filebased-cache-for-web-and-nonweb-apps-plus--extend-aspnet-40-outputcacheprovider.aspx)

Comment: write the cache entities as csv files?

Comment: I don't know if it is possible in C#: in C I would map (mmap) the memory location to a disc location (file). Then the memory and the disc file would allways be the same. Probably some C# guru here will give you a better answer ;)

Comment: There is something wrong in your application design if it fails if cache is cleaned. If any item is not found in cache, it should be gotten from its source place.

Comment: @KirillBestemyanov I think he understands that. (Note the "I know... what did they think a cache was!?") It's not his design - he's trying to keep it running before it can be replaced.

Comment: @KirillBestemyanov That's exactly right, thanks :-)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This link did work, so it's going to be my answer. Thanks for everyone's help!

[File-Based Cache for Web and non-Web Apps plus Extend ASP.NET 4.0 OutputCacheProvider](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/tutorials/asp-net/56161e9e-7fa3-48e8-9dfe-9f7a28f4d58e/filebased-cache-for-web-and-nonweb-apps-plus--extend-aspnet-40-outputcacheprovider.aspx)

Comment: The link isn't working anymore...
I was here to find a way to save object to disk as BinaryFormatter has been discouraged since .Net5 onwards.

Answer (score 5):

You can write own "serialization" using reflections, get all primitive fields and save it as class path and value. it will be long operation but you will can save class as file. Better solution is use real serialization.

Comment: It will not work with some injected properties and so on (as example - dbcontext in ef or else).

Comment: This sounds like a lot of work. Or is it not so bad, perhaps there are some libraries that will do this for me?